# SDK flutter packages conflict

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.6.  Because date_time_picker >=2.0.0 depends on intl ^0.17.0 and date_time_picker <2.0.0 doesn't support null safety, every version of date_time_picker requires intl ^0.17.0. And because every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.18.0, date_

When i type pub get the error between these packages occur

```
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.6.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.0 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  app_settings: any
  badges: any
  barcode_scan2: any
  cached_network_image: any
  #  call_log: any
  connectivity: any
#  cron: any
  cupertino_icons: any
  date_time_picker: any
  dio: any
  flutter_html_to_pdf: any
  flutter_kurdish_localization: ^1.0.1
  fluttertoast: any
  geolocator: 8.2.1
  awesome_dialog: any
  flutter_speed_dial: any
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: any

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  image_path: "assets/icon/pos.png"

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - i18n/
```

I tried changing sdk environment but did succeed. Please help

Comment: Can you provide all depedencies on pubspec.yaml? based on the error, the conflict is becaise the date_time_picker and intl version, not from flutter sdk

Comment: added the pubspec file

Answer (score 1):

Each version of `date_time_picker` is using `intl 0.17.0`.
while each version of `flutter_localizations` is using `intl 0.18.0`.
The issue occurs because the `intl` package is not match.

Even if you don't add the `intl` package to your project dependencies. But `flutter_localizations` and `date_time_picker` use package `intl`, so if there are several packages that use packages with different versions, this conflict can occur. You can check the package depedencies on the right side (check the image below).

[image: Depedencies info].

There are several ways to solve this problem:

1. Ask the authors to update his package to use a newer intl version.
   But there are users who have asked to update the package due to a
   similar error as you asked
   https://github.com/m3uzz/date_time_picker/issues/85
2. Fork the `date_time_picker` repository and update the `intl` version by yourself.
3. Downgrade the flutter sdk.