# i can not add flutterfire_ui Because every version of flutterfire_ui depends from sdk which depends on intl 0.18.0

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec.yaml

when i try to add flutterfire_ui  i get this massage

Because every version of flutterfire_ui depends on flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.18.0, every version of flutterfire_ui requires intl 0.18.0.
So, because fresume_app depends on both intl ^0.18.1 and flutterfire_ui any, version solving failed.

[image]

i add the intl: ^0.18.1 already

Comment: Your issue looks similiar like this one I just answered, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76751534/13096991). Hope that helps!